# "jekyll build --lsi" make blog very very slow

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I created a blog with jekyll. 
Recently related_posts only recommends the latest posts.

I recently used the `jekyll build - lsi` command to do a good post recommendation.

You can read this part at https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/ link.
In summary, the liquid variable updates the `site.related_posts` section to index the relevant posts.

By the way, after that, the build is so slow that it is still slow, even though I've erased all the related gems. _config related variables
I do not know how I can get back to it ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the very same page you linked to in your question:

> For high quality but slow to compute results, run the  `jekyll` command with the `--lsi` (latent semantic indexing) option.

So, the "slowness" is a documented and expected side-effect to using the `--lsi` option.

If you feel, the "extra slowness" is seen only in `v3.8.x` and not in the previous versions, I highly recommend that you [open an issue](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/new) at Jekyll's GitHub repo.

Answer (score 1):

The `--lsi` option comes from the [`classifier-reborn`](https://jekyll.github.io/classifier-reborn/) gem, which includes the following note about increasing speed under the [dependencies](https://jekyll.github.io/classifier-reborn/#dependencies) heading:

> To speed up LSI classification by at least 10x consider installing
> following libraries.
>
> [GSL - GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl)
>
> [Ruby/GSL Gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/gsl)
>
> Note that LSI will work without these libraries, but as soon as they
> are installed, classifier will make use of them. No configuration
> changes are needed, we like to keep things ridiculously easy for you.

The [`gsl` gem's installation docs](https://github.com/SciRuby/rb-gsl#installation) mentions:

> the GSL libraries must already be installed before Ruby/GSL can be installed:
>
> - Debian/Ubuntu: +libgsl0-dev+
> - Fedora/SuSE: +gsl-devel+
> - Gentoo: +sci-libs/gsl+
> - OS X: `brew install gsl`

The [`gsl` gem can also make use of `nmatrix` or `narray`](https://github.com/SciRuby/rb-gsl#nmatrix-and-narray-usage), which I believe may further increase the speed/efficiency:

> In order to use rb-gsl with NMatrix you must first set the NMATRIX
> environment variable and then install rb-gsl:
>
> - `gem install nmatrix`
> - `export NMATRIX=1`
> - `gem install rb-gsl`
>
> This will compile rb-gsl with NMatrix specific functions.
>
> For using rb-gsl with NArray:
>
> - `gem install narray`
> - `export NARRAY=1`
> - `gem install rb-gsl`
>
> Note that setting both `NMATRIX` and `NARRAY` variables will lead to
> undefined behaviour. Only one can be used at a time.

I'm not sure whether `nmatrix` or `narray` is the better/faster choice, though I did open `https://github.com/jekyll/classifier-reborn/issues/192` on the `classifier-reborn` repo.

I did notice that the old [narray GitHub repo](https://github.com/masa16/narray#new-version-is-under-development---rubynumonarray) mentions that the package is no longer maintained, and instead links to a new version: [Ruby/Numo::NArray](https://github.com/ruby-numo/narray)

> Numo::NArray is an Numerical N-dimensional Array class for fast processing and easy manipulation of multi-dimensional numerical data, similar to numpy.ndaray. This project is the successor to Ruby/NArray.

Numo::NArray also links to [`numo-gsl`](https://github.com/ruby-numo/numo-gsl), which appears to be related gsl bindings:

> GSL interface for Ruby/Numo::NArray

At this stage i'm not sure if `classifier-reborn` is able to make use of any of these numo dependencies, but if it can, my guess is that they are going to be faster/more actively maintained.